# How do you customize where the redirect request gets sent to after sign-in in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've found a seemingly solution to my problem but I keep on getting an internal server error.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user_path
end
```

I currently have a user model and an admin model and I want both to go to the same web page. Is what the method `after_sign_in_path_`for takes in as a parameter supposed to be the model I want to use? I'm not sure what the `(resource)` is in this context...

Comment: Can I see the error logs please? What you have should, I think, on the face of it work. You're right 'resource' refers to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think **def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) is already correct**, the only problem is current_user_path, you can use as follow

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_path(current_user)
end
```